# Change JSON structure to send in API post request

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api, angular8

I am making an API POST call in Angular 8. I have to send a JSON object in the call which should be of structure:

```
-{}JSON
  -{}data
     -[]exp
        +{} 0
        +{} 1
```

but I am sending data in this format:

```
-[]JSON
   +{} 0
   +{} 1
```

in my typescript I am getting two objects `{}0, {}1` in array called: `receivedData` then I am storing the data like:

```
this.changedData = this.receivedData;
this.postService.postMethod(this.headers, this.changedData)
```

in my postService:

```
postMethod(header, changedData): Observable<any[]> {
return this.http.post<any>(`the url here`, changedData, {headers: header, responseType: 'text' as 'json'})
.pipe(map(response => {
return response;
}))
}
```

how to send data in the mentioned format? I want the json structure of `changedDetails` to be as mentioned on the top with the same naming convention like: `{}data and []exp` How can I push `receivedData objects` into `exp[]` which I can then send into `data{}` which will then be entirely pushed into `changedDetails {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so we're on the same page, I'm imagining you're receiving data with the following shape:

```
[ { ... },  { ... } ]
```

And you want to transform it to this shape:

```
{
  data: {
    exp: [ { ... }, { ... } ]
  }
}
```

(Let me know if this is not the case.)
If this is correct, than the transformation is quite straightfoward: simply create a new object literal like so:

```
this.changedData = {
  data: {
    exp: this.receivedData,
  },
};
```

Comment: I am at the same spot but how do I do it in Angular 8 typescript? How can I convert my data into the format you mentioned. Typescript will give errors, right?

Comment: It depends on if `this.changedData` has been declared, and what type it has been given. Have you tried it out to see if it produces any errors?

Comment: wow this worked like a charm. I am relatively new to Angular and did not know we can play around with the JSON structure this easily. Thank you. marked as the accepted answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad that helped. Yeah, JavaScript/TypeScript allow you to do quite a lot of "peeking around". Cheers!